# How to convert and transmit PHP Variable data Using JSON to HTML page's Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, json

I can't seem to figure it out how to convert the following PHP variable to HTML:

```
$persondata = "<div id='teach'><h3>Name: " . $row["fname"]. "<br>User Name: " . $row["username"]. "</h3><p>Password: " . $row["upass"]. "</p></div><br>";
```

I wanted to pass that *exact* data to my HTML page, so that I can use JavaScript's `getElementById` function to insert it into a selected data field.

I asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42189525/how-can-one-create-multiple-rows-with-javascript-not-normal-rows), which helped me work out some of logic I need, but I can't work out this part of the equation.

If you could please let me know of a simple way of going about this, it would be very much appreciated, as I don't even know the keywords to search for.

Comment: `All i want is to convert this php variable` into what? I mean do you want to use `json` data to populate HTML page using javascript?

Comment: convert it using JSON and send it to a javascript variable in my HTML. I don't know what conversion method i have to use to transmit it there without it loosing any of its form...

Comment: yes but it that exact for coz i found out that innerHTML accepts this form and translates it very well...

Answer (score 0):

A javaScriptVar equals with an echo in php of your php variable.

That is to put php inside js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//Your JS

var jsvar = <?php echo $persondata; ?>

//Your JS
</script>
```

Put PHP var like above into js.

Comment: uuuuuhhhhhh I don't get it... ... ... *3 mins later* Still don't get it...

Comment: var jsvar = <?php echo $persondata;?> try this.Or use json.

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from above answer:

That is to put php inside js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//Your JS

var jsvar = <?php echo $persondata; ?>;

//Your JS
</script>
```

Put PHP var like above into js.

If you want to transmit data from a PHP script in a server to a client side HTML page for using in js. Go like following.

1. First get all your data in PHP in an array and use `json_encode()` and after that `echo` that variable.
2. Now in the client side HTML use `jQuery.ajax()` and send request to that PHP file in server.
3. When you have the response in Json use js to fragment it and append
   wherever you want.

Above is the basic procedure to send data from PHP to HTML page using JS.

Comment: but how do you transmit it from the php page to the HTML page?

Comment: So, are you not generating HTML from a PHP page? Or tell me a bit about your file structure?

Comment: their both foreign from each other. it's basically a long distance relationship where the HTML page is separate from the PHP page. This is why i said i needed to convert it to JSON to transmit it from the php page to the html page.

Answer (score 0):

Hope below code help you:

```
<?php
$persondata = '';
foreach($rows as $row){
 $persondata .= "<div class='teach'><h3>Name: " . $row["fname"]. "<br>User Name: " . $row["username"]. "</h3><p>Password: " . $row["upass"]. "</p></div><br>";
}

?>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function () {
         $('#data-row').html("<?php echo $persondata ?>");
      });
    </script>
</head>
<div id="data-row"></div>
```

Comment: sadly this could only handle one row... i need the code to give me more than one row... (number of rows is undefined)

Comment: you can use foreach() function to append multiple rows

Comment: wait where do i put that?

Comment: I think you are looking for AJAX in both js and php